# Kalman gain derivation, how to prove that minimization problem is convex?

Tags: kalman-filter

I follow [www.kalmanfilter.net](https://www.kalmanfilter.net/kalmanGain.html) to try derivation kalman filter my self.
I've notice that the cost function is SSEs which clearly convex. but look at "Differentiate the trace of Pn,n with respect to Kn"

$$ \frac{d }{dK_n}tr(P_{n,n}) = −2(HP_{n,n−1})^T+2K_n(HP_{n,n−1}H^T+Rn) $$

How can we tell that $$  tr(P_{n,n}) $$ is convex  respect to Kn so we can prove it optimal?

First, I think second derivative isn't work because trace is scalar, Differentiate trace by matrix is matrix. to derivative that matrix isn't make sense for me.

Secondly, I look at the equation. I think that first term is constant and
$$  HP_{n,n−1}H^T+Rn $$
is positive definite if assumed this is linear equation, the slope of derivative is greater than zero, so the function its self must be covex quadratic equation.
If I was right, then how to prove it mathematically?